# Boolean algebra with the definition of Huntington - prove de morgan's law without the use of associativity

Tags: boolean-algebra

I started with the definition of boolean algebras by Huntington, which is:

> A boolean algebra is a set $B$ with two operations on $B$, so that for
>   all $a \in B$, $b \in B$ and $c \in B$ holds:
>
> Commutativity: \begin{equation}\label{1.1.1}\tag{1.1.1}
>      a \land b = b \land a \end{equation} \begin{equation}\label{1.1.2}\tag{1.1.2}
>      a \lor b = b \lor a \end{equation} Distributivity: \begin{equation}\label{1.1.3}\tag{1.1.3}
>      a \land \left(b \lor c \right) = \left(a \land b\right) \lor \left(a \land c \right) \end{equation} \begin{equation}\label{1.1.4}\tag{1.1.4}
>      a \lor \left(b \land c \right) = \left(a \lor b\right) \land \left(a \lor c \right) \end{equation} Existence of neutral elements:
>   There are elements $0 \in B$ and $1 \in B$, so that:
>   \begin{equation}\label{1.1.5}\tag{1.1.5}
>      a \land 1 = a \end{equation} \begin{equation}\label{1.1.6}\tag{1.1.6}
>      a \lor 0 = a \end{equation} Existence of complements: For every $a\in B$ there is $\neg a\in B$, so that:
>   \begin{equation}\label{1.1.7}\tag{1.1.7}
>      a \land \neg a = 0 \end{equation} \begin{equation}\label{1.1.8}\tag{1.1.8}
>      a \lor \neg a = 1 \end{equation}

---

I wanted to prove, that from this definition everything stated [here](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolesche_Algebra#Definition) follows. I was able to do this, but I used the associativity to finally prove de morgan's law. Nevertheless I am pretty sure, that you don't need associativity to prove de morgan's law. Could one give me a hint on how to achieve that?

For everbody interested in how I've proven everything (de morgan's law is corollary $\ref{2.11}$):

---

Corollary 2.1 $\label{2.1}\tag{2.1}$

> There is one and only one $0 \in B$.

Be $0_1 \in B$ and $0_2 \in B$ zero elements. It holds:
\begin{equation*}
0_1 \overset{\ref{1.1.6}}{=} 0_1 \lor 0_2 \overset{\ref{1.1.2}}{=} 0_2 \lor 0_1 \overset{\ref{1.1.6}}{=} 0_2
\end{equation*}
$\Box$

Corollary 2.2 $\label{2.2}\tag{2.2}$

> There is one and only one $1 \in B$.

Be $1_1 \in B$ and $1_2 \in B$ one elements. It holds:
\begin{equation*}
1_1 \overset{\ref{1.1.5}}{=} 1_1 \land 1_2 \overset{\ref{1.1.1}}{=} 1_2 \land 1_1 \overset{\ref{1.1.5}}{=} 1_2
\end{equation*}
$\Box$

Corollary 2.3 $\label{2.3}\tag{2.3}$

> There is one and only one $\neg a \in B$ for each $a \in B$.

Be $a \in B$ and be $a_1 \in B$ and $a_2 \in B$ complements of $a$. It holds:
\begin{equation*}
a_1 \overset{\ref{1.1.6}}{=} a_1 \lor 0 \overset{\ref{1.1.7}}{=} a_1 \lor \left(a \land a_2 \right) \overset{\ref{1.1.4}}{=} \left(a_1 \lor a \right) \land \left(a_1 \lor a_2  \right)
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\overset{\ref{1.1.2}}{=} \left(a \lor a_1 \right) \land \left(a_1 \lor a_2  \right) \overset{\ref{1.1.8}}{=} 1 \land \left(a_1 \lor a_2  \right) \overset{\ref{1.1.8}}{=} \left(a \lor a_2 \right) \land \left(a_1 \lor a_2  \right)
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\overset{\ref{1.1.2}}{=} \left(a_2 \lor a \right) \land \left(a_2 \lor a_1  \right) \overset{\ref{1.1.4}}{=} a_2 \lor \left(a \land a_1 \right) \overset{\ref{1.1.7}}{=} a_2 \lor 0 \overset{\ref{1.1.6}}{=} a_2
\end{equation*}
$\Box$

Corollary 2.4 $\label{2.4}\tag{2.4}$

> For $a \in B$ holds: $$\neg \neg a = a$$

Be $a \in B$, be $\neg a \in B$ the complement of $a$ and be $\neg \neg a \in B$ the complement of $\neg a$. It holds:
\begin{equation*}
\neg \neg a \overset{\ref{1.1.6}}{=} \neg \neg a \lor 0 \overset{\ref{1.1.7}}{=} \neg \neg a \lor \left(a \land \neg a \right)
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\overset{\ref{1.1.4}}{=} \left(\neg \neg a \lor a \right) \land \left(\neg \neg a \lor \neg a \right) \overset{\ref{1.1.2}}{=} \left(a \lor \neg \neg a \right) \land \left(\neg a \lor \neg \neg a \right)
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\overset{\ref{1.1.8}}{=} \left(a \lor \neg \neg a \right) \land 1 \overset{\ref{1.1.8}}{=} \left(a \lor \neg \neg a \right) \land \left(a \lor \neg a \right) \overset{\ref{1.1.4}}{=} a \lor \left(\neg \neg a \land \neg a \right)
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\overset{\ref{1.1.1}}{=} a \lor \left(\neg a \land \neg \neg a \right) \overset{\ref{1.1.7}}{=} a \lor 0 \overset{\ref{1.1.6}}{=} a
\end{equation*}
$\Box$

Corollary 2.5 $\label{2.5}\tag{2.5}$

> It holds $$\neg 0 = 1$$ and $$\neg 1 = 0$$

\begin{equation*}
\neg 0 \overset{\ref{1.1.6}}{=} \neg 0 \lor 0 \overset{\ref{1.1.5}}{=} \neg 0 \lor \left(0 \land 1 \right) \overset{\ref{1.1.4}}{=} \left(\neg 0 \lor 0 \right) \land \left(\neg 0 \lor 1 \right)
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\overset{\ref{1.1.2}}{=} \left(0 \lor \neg 0 \right) \land \left(1 \lor \neg 0 \right) \overset{\ref{1.1.8}}{=} 1 \land \left(1 \lor \neg 0 \right) \overset{\ref{1.1.6}}{=} \left(1 \lor 0 \right) \land \left(1 \lor \neg 0 \right)
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\overset{\ref{1.1.4}}{=} 1 \lor \left(0 \land \neg 0 \right) \overset{\ref{1.1.7}}{=} 1 \lor 0 \overset{\ref{1.1.6}}{=} 1
\end{equation*}
With \ref{2.4} we have:
\begin{equation*}
0 = \neg \neg 0 = \neg 1    
\end{equation*}
$\Box$

Corollary 2.6 $\label{2.6}\tag{2.6}$

> For every $a \in B$ holds: $$a \lor a = a$$ and $$a \land a = a$$

Be $a \in B$. It holds:
\begin{equation*}
a \lor a \overset{\ref{1.1.5}}{=} \left(a \lor a \right) \land 1 \overset{\ref{1.1.8}}{=} \left(a \lor a \right) \land \left(a \lor \neg a \right)
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\overset{\ref{1.1.4}}{=} a \lor \left(a \land \neg a \right) \overset{\ref{1.1.7}}{=} a \lor 0 \overset{\ref{1.1.6}}{=} a
\end{equation*}
By the duality principle follows the second part.
$\Box$

Corollary 2.7 $\label{2.7}\tag{2.7}$

> For all $a \in B$ holds: $$a \lor 1 = 1$$ and $$a \land 0 = 0$$

Be $a \in B$. It holds:
\begin{equation*}
a \lor 1 \overset{\ref{1.1.5}}{=} \left(a \lor 1 \right) \land 1 \overset{\ref{1.1.1}}{=} 1 \land \left(a \lor 1 \right) \overset{\ref{1.1.8}}{=} \left(a \lor \neg a \right) \land \left(a \lor 1 \right)
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\overset{\ref{1.1.4}}{=} a \lor \left(\neg a \land 1 \right) \overset{\ref{1.1.5}}{=} a \lor \neg a \overset{\ref{1.1.8}}{=} 1
\end{equation*}
By the duality principle follows the second part.
$\Box$

Corollary 2.8 $\label{2.8}\tag{2.8}$

> For all $a \in B$ and $b \in B$ holds: $$a \land \left(a \lor b
>  \right) = a$$ and $$a \lor \left(a \land b \right) = a$$

Be $a \in B$ and $b \in B$. It holds:
\begin{equation*}
a \land \left(a \lor b \right) \overset{\ref{1.1.6}}{=} \left(a \lor 0 \right) \land \left(a \lor b \right) \overset{\ref{1.1.4}}{=} a \lor \left(0 \land b \right) \overset{\ref{1.1.1}}{=} a \lor \left(b \land 0 \right)
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\overset{\ref{2.7}}{=} a \lor 0 \overset{\ref{1.1.6}}{=} a
\end{equation*}
By the duality principle follows the second part.
$\Box$

Lemma 2.9 $\label{2.9}\tag{2.9}$

> Be $a \in B$, $b \in B$ and $c \in B$ with $$a \lor c = b \lor c$$ and
>    $$a \lor \neg c = b \lor \neg c$$ It follows: $$a = b$$ Also holds,
>    that from $$a \land c = b \land c$$ and $$a \land \neg c = b \land
>  \neg c$$ follows: $$a = b$$

Be $a \in B$, $b \in B$ and $c \in B$ with $$a \lor c = b \lor c$$ and $$a \lor \neg c = b \lor \neg c$$
It holds:
\begin{equation*}
a \overset{\ref{1.1.6}}{=} a \lor 0 \overset{\ref{1.1.7}}{=} a \lor \left(c \land \neg c \right)
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\overset{\ref{1.1.4}}{=} \left(a \lor c \right) \land \left(a \lor \neg c \right) = \left(b \lor c \right) \land \left(b \lor \neg c \right)
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\overset{\ref{1.1.4}}{=} b \lor \left(c \land \neg c \right) \overset{\ref{1.1.7}}{=} b \lor 0 \overset{\ref{1.1.6}}{=} b
\end{equation*}
By the duality principle follows the second part.
$\Box$

Corollary 2.10 $\label{2.10}\tag{2.10}$

> For all $a \in B$, $b \in B$ and $c \in B$ holds: $$a \land \left(b
>  \land c \right) = \left(a \land b\right) \land c$$ and $$a \lor
>  \left(b \lor c \right) = \left(a \lor b\right) \lor c$$

Be $a \in B$, $b \in B$ and $c \in B$. Be also $$x := a \land \left(b \land c \right)$$ and $$y := \left(a \land b\right) \land c$$
It holds:
\begin{equation*}
a \lor x = a \lor \left(a \land \left(b \land c \right) \right) \overset{\ref{1.1.4}}{=} \left(a \lor a \right) \land \left(a \lor \left(b \land c \right) \right)
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\overset{\ref{2.6}}{=} a \land \left(a \lor \left(b \land c \right) \right) \overset{\ref{2.8}}{=} a
\end{equation*}
Also holds:
\begin{equation*}
a \lor y = a \lor \left(\left(a \land b\right) \land c \right) \overset{\ref{1.1.4}}{=} \left(a \lor \left(a \land b\right) \right) \land \left(a \lor c \right)
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\overset{\ref{2.8}}{=} a \land \left(a \lor c \right) \overset{\ref{2.8}}{=} a
\end{equation*}
All in all: $$a \lor x = a \lor y$$
Also holds:
\begin{equation*}
\neg a \lor x = \neg a \lor \left(a \land \left(b \land c \right) \right) \overset{\ref{1.1.4}}{=} \left(\neg a \lor a \right) \land \left(\neg a \lor \left(b \land c \right) \right)
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\overset{\ref{1.1.2}, \ref{1.1.8}, \ref{1.1.1}, \ref{1.1.5}}{=} \neg a \lor \left(b \land c \right)
\end{equation*}
Also holds:
\begin{equation*}
\neg a \lor y = \neg a \lor \left(\left(a \land b\right) \land c \right) \overset{\ref{1.1.4}}{=} \left(\neg a \lor \left(a \land b\right) \right) \land \left(\neg a \lor c \right)
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\overset{\ref{1.1.4}}{=} \left(\left(\neg a \lor a \right) \land \left(\neg a \lor b \right) \right) \land \left(\neg a \lor c \right) \overset{\ref{1.1.2}, \ref{1.1.8}}{=} \left(1 \land \left(\neg a \lor b \right) \right) \land \left(\neg a \lor c \right)
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\overset{\ref{1.1.1}, \ref{1.1.5}}{=} \left(\neg a \lor b \right) \land \left(\neg a \lor c \right) \overset{\ref{1.1.4}}{=} \neg a \lor \left(b \land c \right)
\end{equation*}
All in all: $$\neg a \lor x = \neg a \lor y$$
With \ref{2.9} we get $x = y$, what we wanted to prove.
By the duality principle follows the second part.
$\Box$

Corollary 2.11 $\label{2.11}\tag{2.11}$

> For all $a \in B$ und $b \in B$ holds: $$\neg \left(a \land b \right)
>  = \neg a \lor \neg b$$ and $$\neg \left(a \lor b \right) = \neg a \land \neg b$$

Be $a \in B$ and $b \in B$. It holds:
\begin{equation*}
\left(a \land b \right) \land \left(\neg a \lor \neg b \right) \overset{\ref{2.10}}{=} a \land \left( b \land \left(\neg a \lor \neg b \right) \right)
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\overset{\ref{1.1.3}}{=} a \land \left(\left(b \land \neg a \right) \lor \left(b \land \neg b \right) \right) \overset{\ref{1.1.7}}{=} a \land \left(\left(b \land \neg a \right) \lor 0 \right) \overset{\ref{1.1.6}}{=} a \land \left(b \land \neg a \right)
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\overset{\ref{1.1.1}, \ref{2.10}}{=} \left( a \land \neg a \right) \land b \overset{\ref{1.1.7}}{=} 0 \land b \overset{\ref{1.1.1}, \ref{2.7}}{=} 0
\end{equation*}
Also holds:
\begin{equation*}
\left(a \land b \right) \lor \left(\neg a \lor \neg b \right) \overset{\ref{2.10}}{=} \left( \left(a \land b \right) \lor \neg a \right) \lor \neg b
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\overset{\ref{1.1.2}, \ref{1.1.4}}{=} \left( \left(\neg a \lor a \right) \land \left(\neg a \lor b \right) \right) \lor \neg b
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\overset{\ref{1.1.2}, \ref{1.1.8}}{=} \left( 1 \land \left(\neg a \lor b \right) \right) \lor \neg b \overset{\ref{1.1.1}, \ref{1.1.5}}{=} \left( \neg a \lor b \right) \lor \neg b
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\overset{\ref{2.10}}{=} \neg a \lor \left( b \lor \neg b \right) \overset{\ref{1.1.8}}{=} \neg a \lor 1 \overset{\ref{2.7}}{=} 1
\end{equation*}
With \ref{1.1.7} and \ref{1.1.8} and \ref{2.3} we get: $$\neg \left(a \land b \right) = \neg a \lor \neg b$$
By the duality principle follows the second part.
$\Box$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that you proved that each element has a unique complement without using the associative law.
Given that each element has one and only one complement, in order to prove that
$$\neg (a \wedge b) = \neg a \vee \neg b,$$
it suffices to show that $a \wedge b$ is a complement of $\neg a \vee \neg b$.
Using properties given in the definition,
$$(a \wedge b) \wedge (\neg a \vee \neg b) = (a \wedge b \wedge \neg a) \vee (b \wedge \neg a \wedge \neg b) = 0 \vee 0 = 0,$$
and similarly $(a \wedge b) \vee (\neg a \vee \neg b) = 1$.
Hence $\neg (a \wedge b) = \neg a \vee \neg b$.
The equality $\neg (a \vee b) = \neg a \wedge \neg b$ follows too because the definitions are symmetric with respect to $\wedge$ and $\vee$.

---

**Edit.**
Clearly, I used associativity in $a \wedge b \wedge \neg a = 0$.
Let me try to get around it.
We certainly have that $(a \wedge b) \wedge \neg a = (b \wedge a) \wedge \neg a$. 
First, I'll add another auxiliary result:

> If $x \vee y = x$ and $\neg x \vee y = \neg x$, then $y=0$.

*Proof.*
$$y = (x \wedge \neg x) \vee y = (x \vee y) \wedge (\neg x \vee y) = x \wedge \neg x = 0.$$

Now,
$$a \vee ( (b \wedge a) \wedge \neg a ) = (a \vee (b \wedge a)) \wedge (a \vee \neg a) = a \vee (b \wedge a) = a,$$
and similarly, $\neg a \vee ((b \wedge a) \wedge \neg a) = \neg a$, whence, by the above result, $(b \wedge a) \wedge \neg a = 0$.
Analogously, $b \wedge \neg a \wedge \neg b = 0$.

Comment: But haven't you implicitly used associativity? I haven't proven $a \land b \land \neg a = 0$ at that point. You used distributivity, so it's explicitly $\left(a \land b\right) \land \neg a$. We have commutativity, so we can write it as $\left(b \land a\right) \land \neg a$, but now we need associativity to write $b \land \left(a \land \neg a\right) = b \land 0 = 0$

Comment: You are right, of course. I misread some details in your question and then I gave a lame answer. I'll edit, but it will perhaps be less interesting, because it will contain part of the reasoning used in your proof of associativity. I hope I'll get it right this time :)

Comment: Thanks, @amrsa! I've found another way to prove $\left(a \land b\right) \land \neg a = 0$... As follows: $\left(a \land b\right) \land \neg a = 0 \lor \left(\left(a \land b\right) \land \neg a \right) = \left(a \land \neg a \right) \lor \left(\left(a \land b\right) \land \neg a \right) = \neg a \land \left(a \lor \left(a \land b \right) \right) \overset{absorption}{=} \neg a \land a = 0$

Comment: Yes, that's shorter, thus better than mine one. Great! :)